# How can I name the runs sent online with Caliper?

Tags: java, caliper

I have a benchmark that requires multiple runs to compare the results, since it needs to be compiled with different compilers and compile parameters. When I execute it, the runs are sent online with simple designators: A, B, C, etc.

I'd like to configure Caliper so that I can pass a name for each run. Is that possible?

Comment: doesn't look like, but if its possible through the admin tool, it shouldn't be too difficult to extend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no mechanism to name a run on the client side. You can confirm this by looking at the results JSON file. We considered adding it and decided we'd wait for somebody to request it first. If you file a bug in the [Caliper issues tracker](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/issues/list), we'll take another look at adding the feature.

Comment: I have always wanted this, just not gotten around to it yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/OnlineResults) link, you can rename results of run on the server. But I didn't found any possibility to give a name for run on machine, where is caliper running.